# Is there something similar to Mercurial's Command Server in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, administration

Mercurial's Command Server allows to issue commands to a Mercurial repository over a pipe through a special protocol... it is like a "webservice" of sorts.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer

Is there anything similar in Git in order to manipulate remote Git repositories to do things you need? (like switching to another branch or updating to another revision)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know exactly, what the mercurial command server does, but usually `git` utilizes `ssh` as its primary remote protocol.

```
ssh serverName "cd /path/to/repo; git pull"
ssh serverName "git --git-dir=/path/to/repo pull"
```

Sends a shell command to a remote ssh server `serverName`. As long as the user you log in with has the rights to do it, you can everything, what the remote `git` installation provides.

Comment: You can also use `"git --git-dir=/path/to/repo pull"`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Interesting, didn't knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When Git communicate with a remote host (over SSH / HTTP) it utilizes an internal protocol:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols